# how to calculate pooled standard deviation in R / or how to use the function pooled.sd() in Rstudio

Tags: r, statistics

How do I calculate the pooled standard deviation in R?

Below is the code to my dataset(As my dataset contains many entries I cannot copy-paste it here)

```
install.packages("Sleuth3")
 library(Sleuth3)
 View(ex0126)
```

To find the mean and standard deviation for each group individually(i.e., individual groups are party R and D) I have got it using the below R code.

```
library(Sleuth3)
ex0126
View(ex0126)
#Average of each group individually for party (R,D)
meanOfR <- subset(aggregate(ex0126[, 4:10], list(ex0126$Party), mean, na.rm=TRUE), Group.1=='R')
meanOfR
meanOfD <- subset(aggregate(ex0126[, 4:10], list(ex0126$Party), mean, na.rm=TRUE), Group.1=='D')
meanOfD
#Sample standard deviation for party (R,D)
sdOfR <- subset(aggregate(ex0126[, 4:10], list(ex0126$Party), sd, na.rm=TRUE), Group.1=='R')
sdOfR
sdOfD <- subset(aggregate(ex0126[, 4:10], list(ex0126$Party), sd, na.rm=TRUE), Group.1=='D')
sdOfD
```

But how to find the pooled standard deviation for the above sample standard deviation for **Party R and D**

Answer (score 0):

It depends which pooled estimate you want. Using the most general estimate with unequal size of grouping

```
data(ex0126, package = Sleuth3)
library(dplyr)
#' Calculate pooled variance given a data.frame with columns (var, n) for each group.
#' All other columns are ignored
pooled_var <- function(df){
  var <- if('sd' %in% names(df)) df$sd^2 else df$var
  d <- dim(var)
  if(d[1] != (n <- nrow(df)))
    stop('inconsistent size of variance and n')
  if(length(d) == 2)
    colSums(sweep(var, 1, df$n - 1, '*')) / (sum(df$n) - n)
  else 
    sum(var * ( df$n - 1 )) / (sum(df$n) - nrow(df))
}
ex0126 %>% 
  select(4:10, Party) %>%
  group_by(Party) %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  summarise(var = across(1:6, var), n = n()) %>%
  pooled_var() %>% 
  sqrt()
```

Note that

1. `select` chooses the columns i want to use
2. `na.omit` is used to avoid including missing values in variance calculations
3. `group_by` tells my pipe that everything needs to be done to each group in `Party`
4. `summarise`/`summarize` is used to aggregate a function across rows

   1. `across` is used to perform the same action over multiple columns.
   2. The output of `across` is itself a `tibble` (`data.frame` like structure), so `df$var` becomes a tibble in pooled_var
   3. by default `summarize` calls `ungroup` at the end. All calls following are no longer in each "group".
5. in `pooled_var` Ii assume a column `var` and `n` exist, and simply use standard formulas to calculate the pooled variance.

   1. Within `pooled_var` I handle both single vectors and multiple columns based on whether `df$var` has multiple dimensions or not.
6. And `sqrt` is called at the end to go from `pooled_var` to a pooled standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

### Use the `sample.decomp` function in the `utilities` package

Since you have access to the underlying dataset, it is possible to compute the pooled standard deviation directly on the underlying pooled data.  However, you can also compute the pooled standard deviation from the pooled moments and group sizes.  This is implemented in the `sample.decomp` function in the [`utilities` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=utilities).  This function can compute pooled sample moments from subgroup moments, or compute missing subgroup moments from the other subgroup moments and pooled moments.  It works for decompositions up to fourth order ---i.e., decompositions of sample size, sample mean, sample variance/standard deviation, sample skewness, and sample kurtosis.

---

**How to use the function:** I am going to assume that in addition to computing the moments, you can also compute the sizes of the two groups, which I will designate as `sizeR` and `sizeG`.  You can use the `sample.decomp` function to obtain the pooled sample moments from the subgroup sample moments.

```
#Input the sample statistics for subgroups
N    <- c(sizeR, sizeG)
MEAN <- c(meanOfR, meanOfG)
SD   <- c(sdOfR, sdOfG)

#Compute sample decomposition
library(utilities)
sample.decomp(n = N, sample.mean = MEAN, sample.sd = SD, include.sd = TRUE)
```

Since you have not given the values of your moments and group sizes, I cannot show you the pooled standard deviation you get as your output.  However, the above code will give you a table showing the moments of the input groups and the pooled sample.  This will include the pooled standard deviation.